# Calibration for cropped stereo pairs

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction, disparity-mapping

I have a stereo image pair of say 100x100 resolution. I did calibration and I am able to rectify it properly and calculate disparity for the same. Now I have the cropped image of size 50x50 with ROI based on center. If I have to use the same calibration matrices, what should I do? Rescaling the principle point in camera matrix is enough or do we need to do anything else?

Comment: Just zero pad the images to a make them 100*100. If the ROI is from center, zero pad all 4 borders equally to put 50*50 image in the center.